# convert soft- to hardlinks with cp

Tags: linux, command-line, cp, options, coreutils

The `cp` command's `info`page offers on the option `--preserve=` the following:

> `links`
>         Preserve in the destination files any links between
>         corresponding source files.  Note that *with `-L' or`-H',
>         this option **can** convert symbolic links to hard links*.

followed by an example I don't get [now]; anyhow:

**Question**: How to turn soft- into hardlinks with `cp`? And is there a way back too [converting hard- into softlinks]?

*Secondary Issue*: Where does **can** in the quote above come into play? I understand the purpose of `-L` and `-H`, I'm able to copy fully functional softlinks etc., but so far I didn't manage to turn soft- into hardlinks.

Comment: related: [Convert symlinks to hard links](http://superuser.com/questions/560597/convert-symlinks-to-hard-links)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example in the info page shows you how though the example is a bit hard to follow:

```
$ mkdir c; : > a; ln -s a b; cp -aH a b c; ls -i1 c
74161745 a
74161745 b
```

Let's break that down into its component commands:

- `mkdir c;` : creates the directory `c/`
- `: > a;` : just a quick way of creating an empty file. It is equivalent to `echo "" > a`. `:` is a bash built in which does nothing, see `help :`.
- `ln -s a b` : create a softlink to `a` called `b`. At this point, these are the contents of the current directory:

  ```
  $ ls -l | cc2ter 
  total 4
  -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Oct  9 02:50 a
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    1 Oct  9 02:50 b -> a
  drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Oct  9 02:50 c
  ```

  Note that `b` is a symbolic link (soft link) it does not point to the same inode as `a`:

  ```
  $ ls -i1c a b
  16647344 a
  16647362 b
  ```
- `cp -aH a b c;` : copy files `a` and `b` into directory `c`. This is where the conversion is happening, the options passed to `cp` are:

  ```
  -a, --archive
        same as -dR --preserve=all
  -d    same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
  -H    follow command-line symbolic links in SOURCE
  ```

  The `-H` is necessary because (from `info cp`):

  > When copying from a symbolic link, `cp' normally follows the link
  >   only when not copying recursively.

  Since `-a` activates recursive copying (`-R`), `-H` is needed to follow symbolic links. `-H` means that links are followed despite recursion and will result in hard links being made in the target directory. These are the contents of `c/` after the last step (the first column is the inode number):

  ```
  $ ls -li c 
  total 0
  17044704 -rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 Oct  9 02:50 a
  17044704 -rw-r--r-- 2 terdon terdon 0 Oct  9 02:50 b
  ```

Now as to how exactly it works, as far as I can figure out from playing around with it, `cp --preserve=links` combined with `-L` or `-H` will convert symbolic links to hard links if **both the link and the target are being copied to the *same* directory**.

---

In fact, as the OP [found out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11607068#11607068), at least on Debian systems, `cp --preserve=links` is sufficient to convert symlinks to hard links if the target directory is the same.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to work without the `-H` and/or `-L`. Anyhow: `: > file` was new for me and is great!
Also: According to the UNIX philosophy ["… programs that do one thing and do it well"] there is `ln` for creating links. But then, why not make this possible and makes sense in the workflow :)

Comment: @chirp the link will be _copied_ without the `-H` but it will be a soft link. Adding the `-H` makes it convert to a hard link.

Comment: I've tried it with[out] `-H` and both the copied link and the copied file [the link originally pointed to] share the same inode -> thus are hardlinked. For whatever reason. Is there a place where I can put a screenshot or something as proove? For whatever reasons. I wonder it there is there [still] a misunderstanding from my side. A bug/feature?

Comment: @chirp I just tried the exact command from the `info` page with and without the `-H` and one gave me a hardlink and the other a symlink with different inodes. This was on an ext4 filesystem running Debian and `cp (GNU coreutils) 8.21`. Do you really get different results? If you want to post somewhere, ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Comment: just sent a bug report to coreutils mailing list on a possible bug in the documentation.

Comment: As an FYI, `:` also works for `ksh`, `csh`, and OpenBSD's `sh` (which is really based on `pdksh`).

Comment: So many things learned with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've sent a report on a possible bug to the coreutils team @gnu.org in `info cp` documentation and got this reply:

> The docs are a bit terse here. The main issue is that -a implies -d
>   and that implies --no-dereference which is required to get your
>   commands to work as expected. I.E. --no-dereference is required to
>   stop cp implicitly following symlinks in the source.
>
> To verify and split out the detail being demonstrated here:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir links; : > a; ln -s a b;
> ```
>
> Here we see that -d overrides -H as it comes after. Therefore we will
>   not dereference symlinks in the first place.
>
> ```
> $ rm links/*; cp -H -d a b links
> $ l links/
> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 padraig 1 Oct 10 09:37 b ▪▶ a
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 padraig 0 Oct 10 09:37 a
> ```
>
> Here we see that -H is now honored as it comes last, and therefore
>   symlinks are followed in the source, resulting in hardlinks in the
>   destination.
>
> ```
> $ rm links/*
> $ rm links/*; cp -d -H a b links
> $ l links
> -rw-rw-r--. 2 padraig 0 Oct 10 09:37 b
> -rw-rw-r--. 2 padraig 0 Oct 10 09:37 a
> ```
>
> I'll make the docs a bit more explicit with the following:
>
> ```
> diff --git a/doc/coreutils.texi b/doc/coreutils.texi
> index b273627..aeed4ca 100644
> --- a/doc/coreutils.texi
> +++ b/doc/coreutils.texi
> @@ -8257,9 +8257,11 @@ $ mkdir c; : > a; ln -s a b; cp -aH a b c; ls -i1 c
>  @noindent
> ```
>
> Note the inputs: `@file{b}` is a symlink to regular file `@file{a}`,
>   yet the files in destination directory, `@file{c/}`, are hard-linked.
>
> - Since `@option{-a}` implies `@option{--preserve=links}`, and since `@option{-H}` tells `@command{cp}` to dereference command line
>     arguments, it sees two files with the same inode number, and preserves
>     the perceived hard link.
> - Since `@option{-a}` implies `@option{--no-dereference}` it would copy the symlink, but the later `@option{-H}` tells `@command{cp}` to
>     dereference the command line arguments where it then sees two files
>     with the same inode number.    Then the `@option{--preserve=links}`
>     option also implied by `@option{-a}` will preserve the perceived hard
>     link.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be difficult to convert hard links to symlinks.  In the case of a hard link, there is a data block on the filesystem which has two or more file entries pointing at it.  There is no "source" and "destination"; it's literally one file with multiple equivalent names.  You can use GNU find to identify those this way:

```
sauer@zipper:~$ find . -type f -links +1 -printf "%i: %p (%n)\n"
609: ./link1 (2)
609: ./link2 (2)
```

Once you've got all of the files with the same inode, you'd have to pick one to be the "real" file and then just replace all of the others with symlinks to the master file.  Probably the way to do that would be to use this:

```
sauer@zipper:~$ find . -type f -links +1 -printf "%i %p\n" | sort -nk1
609 ./link1
609 ./link2
```

And then have a script figure out how to pick one of the values with the same number to have all the others link to it.  Maybe the first one becomes the target, and any more with the same inode are symlinked to it.  Here's one really simple, untested shell script example

```
#!/bin/sh
prev=""
target=""
find /tmp -type f -links +1 -printf "%i %p\n" | sort -nk1 \
| while read inode file
do
  if [[ $inode != $prev ]]
  then
     target="$file"
     prev=$inode
  else
    ln -sf "$target" "$file"
  fi
done
```

There are potential problems, in that links from different directories may be created with an invalid target if the path in find (/tmp in this example) is not absolute.  But the general idea should be fine.

Comment: Nice answer, but it doesn't answer the Question, instead it  would answer how to [convert-a-hardlink-into-a-symbolic-link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171788/convert-a-hardlink-into-a-symbolic-link)

Comment: I created a script that takes working directory and source directory as options: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7a9a83695a28412abbcd

Comment: You should add `-v` for verbose to the `ln` command, and at first just write `echo ln -sfv "$target" "$file"` to see what would happen, otherwise this would be really dangerous. If everything looks fine, you can remove the `echo`

Comment: The question says the man page explains how to go symlink->hardlink and there was already an answer for that; I answered the remaining question about how to go back.  Adding a `-v` only tells you what blew up, but yes, good point about running with an echo at first.