# Is `who mom likes` a real linux command?

Tags: who, whoami

I stumbled across a blog that mentioned the following command.

```
who mom likes
```

It appears to be equivalent to

```
who am i
```

The author warns to never enter the following into the command line (I suspect he is being facetious)

```
who mom hates
```

There is nothing documented about the `mom` command. What does it do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes it's a joke, included in by the developers of the `who` command. See the man page for `who`.

*excerpt*

> If  FILE is not specified, use /var/run/utmp.  /var/log/wtmp as FILE is common.  If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual.

This U&L Q&A titled: [What is a "non-option argument"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96703/what-is-a-non-option-argument/96777#96777) explains some of the terminology from the man page and my answer also covers alternatives to `who .. ...`. commands.

#### Details

There really isn't anything special about `am I` or `am i`. The `who` command is designed to return the same results for any 2 arguments. Actually it behaves as if you called it with its `-m` switch.

```
   -m     only hostname and user associated with stdin
```

*Examples*

```
$ who -m
saml     pts/1        2014-01-06 09:44 (:0)
$ who likes candy
saml     pts/1        2014-01-06 09:44 (:0)
$ who eats cookies
saml     pts/1        2014-01-06 09:44 (:0)
$ who blah blah
saml     pts/1        2014-01-06 09:44 (:0)
```

#### Other implementations

If you take a look at [The Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/index.html), you can gain access to an older implementation of `who`.

> > [The *Heirloom Toolchest*](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html) is a
> >     collection of standard Unix utilities.
> >
> > Highlights are:
> >
> > - **Derived from original Unix material** released as Open Source by [Caldera](http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Caldera-license.pdf) and
> >       [Sun](http://www.opensolaris.org/).

The man page that comes with this `who` in this distribution also has the same "feature", except it's more obvious.

```
$ groff -Tascii -man who.1 |less
...

SYNOPSIS
       who [-abdHlmpqRrstTu] [utmp_file]
       who -q [-n x] [utmp_file]
       who [am i]
       who [am I]
...
...
       With the two-argument synopsis forms `who am i' and  `who  am  I',  who
       tells who you are logged in as.
...
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The command is `who`.  You can give it any argument such as `mom likes` and Linux won't complain.  Its purpose is to get a list of people logged into the system.

Comment: Ah! you are right, who foo bar returns the same result.