# Convert a hardlink into a symbolic link

Tags: files, symlink, hard-link, ln

It is easy to convert a symlink into a hardlink with `ln -f` ([example](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/dc048d1a4dcf2d09c3a4))

It would also be easy to convert a hardlink (filenames `link` and `original`) back to a symbolic link to `link->original` in the case where you know both files and define yourself which one is the "original file". You could easily create a simple script `convert-known-hardlink-to-symlink` that would result in something like:

```
convert-known-hardlink-to-symlink link original
$ ls -li
3802465 lrwxrwxrwx 1 14 Dec  6 09:52 link -> original
3802269 -rw-rw-r-- 1  0 Dec  6 09:52 original
```

But it would be really useful if you had a script where you could define **a working directory** (default `./`) and a **search-directory where to search** (default `/`) for files with the same inode and then convert all those hard-links to symbolic-links.

The result would be that in the defined working directory all files that are hard-links are replaced with symbolic-links to the first found file with the same inode instead.

---

A start would be `find . -type f -links +1 -printf "%i: %p (%n)\n"`

Comment: I'm not sure about this but i guess its impossible without checking EVERY file on your disk since hardlinks usually don't know, which are the other file(-names) which point to the same area on your harddisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a script that will do this. The script converts all hard-links it finds in a source directory (first argument) that are the same as in the working directory (optional second argument) into symbolic links:

https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7a9a83695a28412abbcd

It has an option -n for a dry-run, that doesn't do anything but shows what would be done.

Main part:

```
$WORKING_DIR=./
#relative source directory from working directory:
$SOURCE_DIR=../otherdir/with/hard-links/with-the-same-inodes

# find all files in WORKING_DIR
cd "$WORKING_DIR"
find "." -type f -links +1 -printf "%i %p\n" | \
  while read working_inode working_on
do
    find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f -links +1 -printf "%i %p\n" | sort -nk1 | \
      while read inode file
    do
        if [[ $inode == $working_inode ]]; then
            ln -vsf "$file" "$working_on"
        fi
    done
done
```

*The -links +1 --> Will find all files that have MORE than 1 link. Hardlinked files have a link count of at least two.*

Answer (score 1):

At least `GNU find` also lets you search by Inode, either numerical (`-inode`) or by specifying the link (`-samefile`).

So you could use:

```
find "$WORKING_DIR" -type f -links +1 | while read file
do
  find "$SOURCE_DIR" -samefile "$file" -exec ln -vsf '{}' "$file" \;
done
```

You just have to make sure to use separate directories. On the other hand, `ln` would complain if you tried to link a file into itself.

Also, you should either provide an absolute path for `$SOURCE_DIR`, or use the `-r` option with `ln` to create relative links, otherwise the links may become broken.